# jdbcRealm secured folders in JSF2.0 accessed by adding "/faces/faces"

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish

I have web app project (NetBeans 7.1.2+GlassFish 3.1.2) with jdbcRealm secured folders secureuser, and secureadmin. The jdbc security is usual form login, with added security constraints. Glassfish deployment descriptor, and web.xml defined as usual. Servlet configuration is default "/faces/*".

Security works as expected when trying to access urls of the form "localhost8080/app/faces/secureduser/". However, if alternatively "localhost8080/app/faces/faces/secureduser/" is used, security is bypassed. Same goes for the other secured folder.

Adding a "/faces" to the url patterns defined in security constraints, [so that if defined pattern is "/faces/secureduser", then added "/faces/faces/secureduser"] seems to always override the security.

Since the login form is JSF, or the design requirement of the initial page at least being outside security, using a filter on context of the form "app/faces/" cannot be used.

How can security be maintained even if user types in an added prefix "/faces"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a paragraph from Servlet 3.0 Specification on how URL path matching is done:

```
The first successful match is used with no further matches attempted:
```

1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path 
   of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done 
   by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as a 
   path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet 
   container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension. An 
   extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character.
4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will 
   attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a "default" 
   servlet is defined for the application, it will be used. Many containers provide an 
   implicit default servlet for serving content.

The container must use case-sensitive string comparisons for matching

So exact matches take precedence over prefix which takes precedence over extension and finally universal patterns.

So what you can do is just add a universal mapping `/*` with no role specified. The universal mapping is matched at the end and if no role is specified no one can access the resource like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>

<!--No Authorization Required -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/faces/index.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<!--All roles can access -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/faces/users.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

[Servlet 3.0 Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) See Section 12.1 Use of URL paths

Comment: Dear @Ravi, many thanks for your pointer. Although the pattern "/**" does not show the required behaviour, [it still allows /faces/faces to bypass security], what really works is replacing the "/**" with "/faces/faces/*".

Comment: Can you try "/*" instead as I was thinking in terms of Spring context and in web.xml "/**" (ant-style pattern) does not actually work.

Comment: Yes, "/*" works! It blocks all unauthenticated access attempts as desired, including "/faces/faces". But it also blocks the start page index.xhtml from being rendered giving a 403 error. It seems "/faces/faces/*" allows index.xhtml (startup) to be rendered, but further access is properly controlled.

Comment: Did you not mention any security-constraint for index.xhtml? because if you don't mention then it will finally end up being matched to "/*"

Comment: The design requirement was to keep startup index.xhtml out of security constraints. I understand what you are saying though. But we need to see if this can be done without setting any constraints on index.xhtml.

Comment: Then if that is the case add a security-constraint for index.xhtml and do not add any <auth-constraint> element so that the container does not require authentication. Alternatively if you add like this <auth-constraint><role-name>*</role-name></auth-constraint> then it is accessible for every role but after authentication.

Comment: Dear @Ravi, many thanks again for your pointers and the code. Yes, that is how it should be. Its a bit tricky to figure out the first time, but the servlet spec and url parsing rules under security does make this the only way to do it. My heartfelt thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!. Since you are new to SO, please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you in solving your problem. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted your code, could not figure out what is the issue,
Check the following blog

http://jugojava.blogspot.in/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html

your web.xml is where you specify the page access

ex:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

In the above example only admin user will have access to pages under admin folder (Web pages/admin)

**UPDATE**

Just by changing the

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have changed the default /faces/ to *.xhtml.

and also remove all the /faces from the security-contrainst should solve the accessing issues (/faces/faces).

Comment: Yes, the security rule will work for normal navigation redirected from within the app - as you show. This is not in dispute, and I also mentioned this in my original question. The question was : when a user typed the url directly in - after prefixing by an additional "/faces/", the security constraint was bypassed and the folder was accessible to the user. It does need explicit additional security constraints as outlined by Ravi to prevent this sort of bypassing.